# Crop image UIImage for saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage

I have an app that allows users to input an image into the app, and another image will be displayed ontop of that image. It provides a preview function, which shows what it will look like. Th preview works, and so does the app, but landscape photos become squished together when I input them. How can I fix this issue?
Here is the code for the image that the user input. I believe this is the part of the code that is causing the problem.

```
UIImage *bottomImage = imgBackGround.image; //background image
UIImage *image   = imgGradient.image; //foreground image
CGSize newSize;

if(IS_IPHONE_5)
 newSize = CGSizeMake(640, 1136);
else
 newSize = CGSizeMake(640, 960);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[[imgBackGround layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage*theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

bottomImage = imgBackGround.image;

// bottomImage = [self imageByCropping:bottomImage toSize:newSize];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

// Use existing opacity as is
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
```

Comment: Are you want to merge two image (bottom image and top image) and make single image?

Comment: I have already done that @PradhyumanChavda

Comment: I just need the background image to come out aspect fill to the rectangle containing it